# Need advice on the Swift while statement

Tags: ios, swift

The following code got compilation error:

```
var a : Int = 0
var b : Int = 3
var sum : Int = 0

while (sum = a+b) < 2 {

}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot invoke '<' with an argument list of type '((()),
>   IntegerLiteralConvertible)'

How to solve this problem? (Of course I can put **sum** assignment statement out side the **while** statement. But this is not convenient. Any other advice? Thanks

Comment: Swift isn't C. Code that is considered horrible in C often becomes illegal in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many other languages, including C and Objective-C, `sum = a+b` would return the value of `sum`, so it could be compared.

In Swift, this doesn't work. This was done intentionally to avoid a common programmer error. From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html):

> Swift supports most standard C operators and improves several capabilities to eliminate common coding errors. The assignment operator (=) does not return a value, to prevent it from being mistakenly used when the equal to operator (==) is intended.

Since the assignment operator does not return a value, it can't be compared with another value.

It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=), but you could create a new operator or overload one of the compound operators to add this functionality. However, this would be unintuitive to future readers of your code, so you may want to simply move the assignment to a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, assignments propagate their value -- that is, when you call

```
sum = a + b
```

the new value of `sum` is available for another part of the expression:

```
doubleSum = (sum = a + b) * 2
```

Swift doesn't work that way -- the value of `sum` *isn't* available after the assignment, so it can't be compared in your `while` statement. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html):

> This feature prevents the assignment operator (=) from being used by
>   accident when the equal to operator (==) is actually intended. By
>   making if x = y invalid, Swift helps you to avoid these kinds of
>   errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it as a `for` loop, although you'll have to repeat the assignment and addition:

```
for sum = a+b; sum < 2; sum = a+b {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain why your code won't compile. Here is how you can clean it up without calculating `sum` in the while loop (I'm assuming you want to be able to reassign what `sum`'s getter is, elsewhere.):

```
var a = 0, b = 3
var getSum = { a + b }
var sum: Int { return getSum() }

while sum < 2 {
```

...and if you're okay with invoking `sum` with parentheses:

```
var a = 0, b = 3
var sum = { a + b }

while sum() < 2 {
```